# How to run eval.py job for tensorflow object detection models

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection, google-colaboratory

I have trained an object detector using tensorflow's object detection API on Google Colab. After researching on the internet for most of the day, I haven't been able to find a tutorial about how to run an evaluation for my model, so I can get metrics like mAP.

I figured out that I have to use the eval.py from the models/research/object_detection folder, but I'm not sure which parameters should I pass to the script.

Shortly, what I've done so far is, generated the labels for the test and train images and stored them under the object_detection/images folder. I have also generated the train.record and test.record files, and I have written the labelmap.pbtxt file. I am using the faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco model from the tensorflow model zoo, so I have configured the faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco.config file, and stored it in the object_detection/training folder. 
The training process ran just fine and all the checkpoints are stored also in the object_detection/training folder.

Now that I have to evaluate the model, I ran the eval.py script like this:

```
!python eval.py --logtostderr --pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config --checkpoint_dir=training/ --eval_dir=eval/
```

Is this okay? Because this started running fine, but when I opened tensorboard there were only two tabs, namely images and graph, but no scalars. Also, I ran tensorboard with logdir=eval.

I am new to tensorflow, so any kind of help is welcome. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

The setup looks good. I had to wait a long time for the Scalars tab to load/show up alongside the other two - like 10 minutes after the evaluation job finished.

[image]

But at the end of the evaluation job, it prints in the console all the scalar metrics that will be displayed in the Scalars tab:

```
Accumulating evaluation results...
DONE (t=1.57s).
Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.434
Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50      | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.693
Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.75      | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.470
Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= small | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
```

etc.

If you want to use the new `model_main.py` script instead of `legacy/eval.py`, you can call it like

```
python model_main.py --alsologtostderr --run_once --checkpoint_dir=/dir/with/checkpoint/at/one/timestamp --model_dir=eval/ --pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config
```

Note that this new API would require the `optimizer` field in `train_config`, which is probably already in your `pipeline.config` since you're using the same for both training and evaluation.

Comment: where do i get detection rectangles?

Answer (score 5):

For those who are looking to run the new `model_main.py` in evaluation mode only. There is a flag in the parameter that you can set that does just that. That flag is `checkpoint_dir`, if you set it equal to a folder containing past training checkpoints, the model will run in evaluation only.

Hope I can help a few that missed it like myself!
Cheers,

Answer (score 5):

I'll try to expand and complement the previous answers.

If you want to evaluate your model on validation data you should use:

```
python models/research/object_detection/model_main.py --pipeline_config_path=/path/to/pipeline_file --model_dir=/path/to/output_results --checkpoint_dir=/path/to/directory_holding_checkpoint --run_once=True
```

If you want to evaluate your model on training data, you should set 'eval_training_data' as True, that is:

```
python models/research/object_detection/model_main.py --pipeline_config_path=/path/to/pipeline_file --model_dir=/path/to/output_results --eval_training_data=True --checkpoint_dir=/path/to/directory_holding_checkpoint --run_once=True
```

---

I also add comments to clarify some of previous options:

**--pipeline_config_path:** path to "pipeline.config" file used to train detection model. This file should include paths to the TFRecords files (train and test files) that you want to evaluate, i.e. :

```
    ...
    train_input_reader: {
        tf_record_input_reader {
                #path to the training TFRecord
                input_path: "/path/to/train.record"
        }
        #path to the label map 
        label_map_path: "/path/to/label_map.pbtxt"
    }
    ...
    eval_input_reader: {
        tf_record_input_reader {
            #path to the testing TFRecord
            input_path: "/path/to/test.record"
        }
        #path to the label map 
        label_map_path: "/path/to/label_map.pbtxt"
    }
    ...
```

**--model_dir**: Output directory where resulting metrics will be written, particularly "events.*" files that can be read by tensorboard.

**--checkpoint_dir**: Directory holding a checkpoint. That is the model directory where checkpoint files ("model.ckpt.*") has been written, either during training process, or after export it by using "export_inference_graph.py".

**--run_once**: True to run just one round of evaluation.